# Using "Extended Permissions" in Facebook SLRequest

Tags: ios, ios6, social-framework

I am interacting with Facebook from an iOS app. I'd like to avoid OAuth by using SLRequest from iOS 6's Social Framework.

I'd like to use the Facebook API's "read stream" permission, which is classified as an "extended permission." The WWDC 2012 video on social integration says that at the time of WWDC, extended permissions were not available, but that it's subject to change and keep an eye on the documentation.

Has this changed? Even better, where in the docs I'd find this info?